# Powershell script - asking for user input, re-run that section until the input is correct

Tags: powershell, input, dialog

I have a very extensive 300+ line user addition script written in PowerShell designed for non-admins to add users to the Windows domain without needing admin rights (it self-elevates) and without needing to get into ADUC.

There's one section (below) that asks for phone numbers, sanitizes the input and formats them correctly for sync to Azure/O365.  It also checks to make sure the input is 10 digits for office and cellphone, and if they're not throws an error dialog box.  I'd like to find out a way to not only throw that error box in the way, but have the script return to the top of the phone entry code to make them re-enter the numbers after they hit the OK button.  That's where I'm at a loss - having it return to the top of the section.

Thanks in advance!  =)

```
    # Phone code begins here
$phoneform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$phoneform.Text = 'Phone numbers'
$phoneform.Size = '300, 200'
$phoneform.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 120)
$OKButton.Size = '75, 23'
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = 'Ok'
$phoneform.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = '160, 120'
$CancelButton.Size = '75, 23'
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = 'Cancel'
$phoneform.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
$phoneform.Topmost = $True
$phoneform.Add_Shown({ $phoneform.Activate() })

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Work and mobile numbers for $IHIfirstname $IHIlastname"
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,42) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Work"
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,72) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Cellphone"
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,20) 
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objTextBox)

$objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,70) 
$objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,20) 
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objTextBox2) 

if('Ok' -eq $phoneform.ShowDialog()){
    #write-host "form OK button clicked"
}else{
    #Write-Host 'Form cancelled'
exit
}

$worknumber = $objTextBox.text
$cellnumber = $objTextBox2.text
$worknumber = $worknumber -replace '[()-. ]',''
$cellnumber = $cellnumber -replace '[()-. ]',''
#write-host $worknumber
#write-host $cellnumber
$worknumber.Length
$cellnumber.Length
if ($worknumber.Length -eq 0) {$worknumber = "0000000000"}
if ($cellnumber.Length -eq 0) {$cellnumber = "0000000000"}

if (($worknumber.Length -eq 10) -and ($cellnumber.Length -eq 10)) {
#write-host "both match"
$worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(0,"(")
$worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(4,")")
$worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(5," ")
$worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(9,"-")

$cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(0,"(")
$cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(4,")")
$cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(5," ")
$cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(9,"-") }
Else {
write-host "One of these is not 10 digits"
$a= New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$numanswer = $a.popup("
Not enough digits entered
Work Phone - $worknumber
Cell Phone -  $cellnumber", `
0,"Error",0)
If ($numanswer -eq 6) {
exit }

}
# Phone code ends here
```

Comment: `designed for non-admins to add users to the Windows domain`... why....

Comment: What you're looking for are called event handlers

Comment: Because not everyone needs to be a domain admin to get that grunt work done.  And because the script does a LOT on the back-end to format attributes correctly for syncing and makes a bunch of updates that a helpdesk person shouldn't have to do manually and have a crazy step-by-step process.  It's been convenient so far, but I just need this one section to repeatedly ask until the input is the right number of digits.

Comment: You could try wrapping the prompting piece in a `Do { .. } Until ($outputexpected)`

Comment: Ideally that onboarding process of adding AD users is already automated.

Comment: =)  I'm the one automating it.

Comment: If non-administrative users can somehow create user accounts, that seems to me to be a security hole by definition.

Comment: You're not wrong.  But the process isn't intended to be run by anyone, just a limited subset of people who I don't want to necessarily have Domain Admin rights or logons.

Comment: There are AD permissions that can be granted to allow for Account Creation/Modification without granting full Domain Admin rights.  If they have those permissions you wouldn't need to have it self-elevate (Which also begs the question of how you are securing the credentials so that someone can't just go and self-elevate for other reasons)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above, if you wrap the code in do/until you can loop allowing the user to retry entering the data. See below for the updated script. (Also, since everything else is Winforms, I modified the script to use the Winforms MessageBox class instead of calling out to wscript.shell.)

```
do {

# Phone code begins here
$phoneform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$phoneform.Text = 'Phone numbers'
$phoneform.Size = '300, 200'
$phoneform.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 120)
$OKButton.Size = '75, 23'
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = 'Ok'
$phoneform.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = '160, 120'
$CancelButton.Size = '75, 23'
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = 'Cancel'
$phoneform.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
$phoneform.Topmost = $True
$phoneform.Add_Shown({ $phoneform.Activate() })

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Work and mobile numbers for $IHIfirstname $IHIlastname"
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,42) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Work"
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,72) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Cellphone"
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,20) 
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objTextBox)

$objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,70) 
$objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,20) 
$phoneform.Controls.Add($objTextBox2) 

if('Ok' -eq $phoneform.ShowDialog()){
    #write-host "form OK button clicked"
}else{
    #Write-Host 'Form cancelled'
    exit
}

$worknumber = $objTextBox.text
$cellnumber = $objTextBox2.text
$worknumber = $worknumber -replace '[()-. ]',''
$cellnumber = $cellnumber -replace '[()-. ]',''
#write-host $worknumber
#write-host $cellnumber
$worknumber.Length
$cellnumber.Length
if ($worknumber.Length -eq 0) {$worknumber = "0000000000"}
if ($cellnumber.Length -eq 0) {$cellnumber = "0000000000"}

if (($worknumber.Length -eq 10) -and ($cellnumber.Length -eq 10)) {
    #write-host "both match"
    $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(0,"(")
    $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(4,")")
    $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(5," ")
    $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(9,"-")

    $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(0,"(")
    $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(4,")")
    $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(5," ")
    $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(9,"-") 
}
Else 
{
    # Use Winforms MessageBox class instead of VBScript Dialog()
    $result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
        "Not enough digits entered`nWork Phone - $worknumber`nCell Phone -  $cellnumber", 
        "Invalid Phone Number", 
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel)
    if ($result -eq "Retry")
    {
        continue
    }
    else
    {
        exit
    }
}

} until ($false)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn the phone number parsing into a function and have it call itself recursively if the data doesn't validate the way you want it to.  Then just call the function and extract the `worknumber` and `cellnumber` properties from the returned object.  If they click cancel it returns `$false` (and then `$return.worknumber` will not give any results) so can validate for if it's false or just end up with blank data (depending on what you need the script to do at that point.

```powershell
function Get-PhoneNumbers {
    # Create form to obtain phone numbers
    $phoneform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $phoneform.Text = 'Phone numbers'
    $phoneform.Size = '300, 200'
    $phoneform.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 120)
    $OKButton.Size = '75, 23'
    $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
    $OKButton.DialogResult = 'Ok'
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($OKButton)
    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = '160, 120'
    $CancelButton.Size = '75, 23'
    $CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
    $CancelButton.DialogResult = 'Cancel'
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
    $phoneform.Topmost = $True
    $phoneform.Add_Shown( { $phoneform.Activate() })

    $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 20) 
    $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 20) 
    $objLabel.Text = "Work and mobile numbers for $IHIfirstname $IHIlastname"
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

    $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40, 42) 
    $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50, 20) 
    $objLabel.Text = "Work"
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

    $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40, 72) 
    $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20) 
    $objLabel.Text = "Cellphone"
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

    $objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 40) 
    $objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160, 20) 
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($objTextBox)

    $objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 70) 
    $objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160, 20) 
    $phoneform.Controls.Add($objTextBox2)

    # Exit on Cancel rather than proceed on Ok to remove need for else.    
    if ('Cancel' -eq $phoneform.ShowDialog()) {
        return $false
    }

    # Do validation here
    $worknumber = $objTextBox.text
    $cellnumber = $objTextBox2.text
    $worknumber = $worknumber -replace '[()-. ]', ''
    $cellnumber = $cellnumber -replace '[()-. ]', ''
    #write-host $worknumber
    #write-host $cellnumber
    if ($worknumber.Length -eq 0) {$worknumber = "0000000000"}
    if ($cellnumber.Length -eq 0) {$cellnumber = "0000000000"}

    if (($worknumber.Length -eq 10) -and ($cellnumber.Length -eq 10)) {
        #write-host "both match"
        $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(0, "(")
        $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(4, ")")
        $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(5, " ")
        $worknumber = $worknumber.Insert(9, "-")

        $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(0, "(")
        $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(4, ")")
        $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(5, " ")
        $cellnumber = $cellnumber.Insert(9, "-")
        # Return now so that only a valid result returns.
        # Previous attempts will be dropped.
        return [pscustomobject]@{
            WorkNumber = $worknumber
            CellNumber = $cellnumber
        }
    }
    Else {
        # Use Winforms MessageBox class instead of VBScript Dialog()
        $result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
            "Not enough digits entered`nWork Phone - $worknumber`nCell Phone -  $cellnumber", 
            "Invalid Phone Number", 
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel)
        if ($result -eq "Retry") {
            Get-PhoneNumbers
        }
        else {
            return $false
        }
    }
}
```